# Is this dependecy injection pattern thread safe?

Tags: go, dependency-injection, thread-safety

I'm having a hard time coming up with a clean pattern to inject dependencies in a REST server that allows me to write isolated unit tests. The below structure seems to work but I'm not sure if it's thread safe.

**store:**

```golang
package store

type InterfaceStore interface {
    Connect()
    Disconnect()
    User() interfaceUser
}

// Wiring up
type store struct {
    db *mongo.Database
}

func (s *store) Connect() {
    client, err := mongo.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    s.db = client.Database()
}

func (s *store) Disconnect() {
    s.db.Client().Disconnect(context.TODO())
}

func (s *store) User() interfaceUser {
    return &user{s.db}
}


// Exposed from the package to create a store instance
func GetStore() InterfaceStore {
    return &store{}
}


// User related
type interfaceUser interface {
    InsertOne(models.User) (string, error)
}

type user struct {
    db *mongo.Database
}

func (u *user) InsertOne(user models.User) (primitive.ObjectID, error) {
    collection := u.db.Collection(collectionUsers)
    // persisting user in DB
}
```

**server:**

```golang
package server

type server struct{}

func (s *server) Start() {
    storeInstance := store.GetStore()
    storeInstance.Connect()
    defer storeInstance.Disconnect()

    r := gin.Default()
    keys := keys.GetKeys()

    routes.InitRoutes(r, storeInstance)

    port := fmt.Sprintf(":%s", keys.PORT)

    r.Run(port)
}

func CreateInstance() *server {
    return &server{}
}
```

**routes:**

```golang
package routes

func InitRoutes(router *gin.Engine, store store.InterfaceStore) {
    router.Use(middlewares.Cors)

    // createSubrouter creates a Gin routerGroup with the prefix "/user"
    userRoutes(createSubrouter("/user", router), store)
}

func userRoutes(router *gin.RouterGroup, store store.InterfaceStore) {
    controller := controllers.GetUserController(store)

    router.GET("/", controller.Get)
}
```

**controllers:**

```golang
package controllers

type userControllers struct {
    UserService services.InterfaceUser
}

func (u *userControllers) Get(c *gin.Context) {
    userDetails, _ := u.UserService.FetchAllInformation(bson.M{"_id": userData.(models.User).ID})

    utils.RespondWithJSON(c, userDetails)
}

func GetUserController(store store.InterfaceStore) userControllers {
    userService := services.GetUserService(store)

    return userControllers{
        UserService: &userService,
    }
}
```

**services:**

```golang
package services

type InterfaceUser interface {
    FetchAllInformation(bson.M) (*models.User, error)
}

type user struct {
    store store.InterfaceStore
}

func (u *user) FetchAllInformation(filter bson.M) (*models.User, error) {
    user, err := u.store.User().FindOne(filter)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return user, nil
}

func GetUserService(store store.InterfaceStore) user {
    return user{
        store: store,
    }
}
```

By using interfaces I'm able to mock the entire service when writing tests for the controller and I can mock the entire store to test the service component without hitting the DB.

I'm wondering if the store instance is safely shared across the code because the interfaces are no pointers. Does that mean a copy of the `store` is created every time I pass it down the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type user struct {}` definition states `store` is anything that implements the `store.InterfaceStore` interface.

If you look carefully, you're implementing it with pointer receivers. That means the (instance pointed by the) receiver will be shared.

If your mock implements them over the value-type it will be copied on method call and you'll be safe, but it will also mean this mock won't be holding new state after the method calls, which I guess is not what you want.

Bottom line, it's not really about how you defined it in the struct, by value or by reference, but what the methods accept as receiver.

Comment: Thank you. Did I get you right, that in `services` the `fetchAllInformation` method should indeed be a pointer receiver, so that store is not copied, but in my mock the `fetchAllInformation` method should rather be a value receiver so that during the tests the state of the method is not shared?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: If the mock implementation uses only reference receivers, would creating a new instance of the mock for every test also be a viable alternative?

Comment: @Bill_BsB, yes it should be a viable alternative. It would actually be better to preserve state across calls for a single test.